# Data augmentation for numeric data with autoencoder

Tags: python, autoencoder, data-generation, oversampling

I want make new data which is based on existing data.

Existing data has a layout like example link below.

[image: Existing data example]

How can I make new data with autoencoder?

There are so many examples with image data, but I need to make a data with numeric(integer) data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does every row in the picture correspond to one data entry? In other word, is (1,4,3,4,2) a data entry? And what do you mean by "with" autoencoder? Do you want to do data augumentation "for" training an autoencoder? If so, you should provide the meaning of the data. Without knowing the meaning of the data, I can not know which kind of data augmentation is reasonable.